# Function differentiable at one point and nowhere else continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Is it possible to construct such a function? Just wondering.

Specifically, I am thinking of $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(0)$ exists and $f$ is discontinuous for all $x\in\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider

$$ f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       x^2 & : x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
       0 & : x \notin \mathbb{Q}
     \end{array}
   \right. $$